# MySQLi/PHP Search engine doesn't work

Tags: php, database, search, mysqli

So far I have this...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="GET">
<input type="text" size="30" />
</form>

<?php  
$db = "example";  

mysqli_connect("localhost","root","*************");  
mysqli_select_db($db);  
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE search_query = '$q'");  
mysqli_query($query);
$results = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

if($results !=="") {
echo "<a href='$array[0]'>Result 1</a>";
echo "<a href='$array[1]'>Result 2</a>";
// you get the idea
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am wondering why MySQLi is not returning what I searched in the bar. I inserted data into the database manually... it's just not working

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you are executing query before you are creating db connection move this up

```
mysqli_connect("localhost","root","*************");  
mysqli_select_db($db);
```

then execute your query

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE search_query = '$q'");  
$results = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've not given the text in put a name, so where does '$q' come from?

You're not checking that $_GET['name'] exists on the second execution (after they press enter)

You're connecting to the database after you've queried it

Try adding an input name

```
<input type="text" size="30" name="q" />
```

and

```
<?php  

if (array_key_exists('q', $_GET)) {
    ...
    $q = $_GET['q'];
    mysqli_connect("localhost","root","*************");  
    mysqli_select_db($db);  
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE search_query = '$q'");  
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you, I also added the "mysql_query($query);" line so that it actually **Executed** the code

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to open the database connection after you can query the db itself.

Try:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="GET">
<input type="text" size="30" />
</form>

<?php  
$db = "example";  
/* Open connection */
mysqli_connect("localhost","root","*************");  
mysqli_select_db($db);  
/* Query the DB */
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE search_query = '$q'");  
$results = mysqli_fetch_array($query);



if($results !=="") {
echo "<a href='$array[0]'>Result 1</a>";
echo "<a href='$array[1]'>Result 2</a>";
// you get the idea
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using a variable `$q`, but you have not defined it.
You have to set the variable to the value of the search result, like:

```
$q = $_GET['searchvalue']
```